# Почему-то не создается окно в ImGui

Tags: c++, imgui

Почему-то не создается окно. Я новичок в ImGui.

```
#include "imgui/imgui.h"

int main() {
    bool window = true;
    ImGui::Begin("Test", &window);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Если бы все было так просто. :)

ImGui может работать только поверх других графических библиотек, например SDL+OpenGL, GLFW+OpenGL, DirectX, ...

Вместе с ImGui идет куча разных примеров (папка `examples/`), под разные комбинации библиотек. Советую начать например [отсюда](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples/example_glfw_opengl2) (GLFW вместе с OpenGL 2).